# How to update a field in mongodb with a string value starting with dollar sign

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to save a hashed password to mongodb, but the problem seems to be that the resulting string that bcrypt gives starts with a dollar sign. Instead of updating the field, the field is removed.

Here's the relevant code:

```
const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

collection.updateOne({ email }, [
  { $set: { hash } }
]);
```

Comment: Which field you like to update?

Comment: I'm trying to update the hash field. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: That code works when I run it, and updates the field in the database properly

Comment: Did you use bcrypt too @Joe?

Comment: Yes, and the resulting hash started with dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

Then it should be this

```
{ $set: { hash: hash } }
```

Or make it a bit clearer:

```
const hash_value = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
collection.updateOne({ email }, [
  { $set: { "hash": hash_value } }
]);
```

I guess `{ email }` has the same issue, must likely you are looking for `{ email: email }`

See this example:

```
var hash1 = "bar"
var hash2 = "$bar"

db.collection.insertMany([{ _id: 1, hash1: "foo" }, { _id: 2, hash2: "foo" }])

db.collection.updateOne({ _id: 1 }, [{ $set: { hash1 } }]);
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: 2 }, [{ $set: { hash2 } }]);

db.collection.find()


{ "_id" : 1.0, "hash1" : "bar" },
{ "_id" : 2.0 }
```

In Mongo 4.4 and earlier `$` are not permitted, see [Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/core/document/#field-names)

> Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.

MongodB 5.0 adds improved support for the use of (`$`) and (`.`) in field names. There are some restrictions. See [Field Name Considerations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#std-label-crud-concepts-dot-dollar-considerations) for more details.

In general I would not recommend the use of (`$`) and (`.`) in field names. And dynamic field names are bad, anyway.

Comment: No that's not the issue. I'm just using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) in ES6 syntax.

Comment: Looks like shortcut property names are not supported within in aggregation pipeline, see my example.

Comment: I tried it without shorthand notation and it doesn't work either. However, your example does illustrate exactly the issue I'm experiencing. However, I do not understand how your explanation is relevant to this behavior. It talks about field names, but the example doesn't use field _names_ starting with `$`, but field _values_.  I want to set field values, not field names.

Comment: i am at the very same issue and dont know how to fix it. my field value is starting with dollar sign too.